# mysql subquery runs indefinitely

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: I am doing a join and wish to return a query with multiple codenames listed for each GenEx prescription brand. However it looks like the way im doing the join causes it to timeout.

Drugs:

```
ID | GenEx   | CodeName | Desc
----------------------------
1  | Cipro   | Dolvo    | 
2  | Ludavil | Ymir     | 
3  | Cipro   | Alpha    |
```

Medicine:

```
   ID | GenEx    | Price    | 
    ----------------------------
    1  | Cipro   | 4.99     | 
    2  | Ludavil | 12.99    | 
    3  | Benazol | 5.00     |
```

I wish to return:

```
1. GenEx->Cipro, CodeName=>Dolvo,Alpha, Price->4.99
2. GenEx->Ludavil, CodeName=>Ymir, Price->12.99
```

### myquery which never completes:

```
SELECT GenEx, Price
 GROUP_CONCAT(CodeName) as CodeName
 FROM (`Drugs` d) 
 JOIN `Medicine` m ON `m`.`GenEx` = `d`.`GenEx`
 WHERE GenEx
 IN (
 SELECT DISTINCT GenEx
   FROM Drugs
   WHERE codeName IN ('Alpha'))
 ) 
  GROUP BY `GenEx`;
```

Comment: sorry that's the wrong table name fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now updated the aswer as per the last update in the question.

Try this code:

```
SELECT d.`GenEx`, d.`CodeName`, d.`Price`,
 GROUP_CONCAT(d.`CodeName`) as CodeName
 FROM Drugs d
 JOIN Medicine m 
 ON m.`GenEx` = d.`GenEx`
 AND d.`GenEx`
 IN (
 SELECT DISTINCT `GenEx`
   FROM drugs
   WHERE codeName IN ('Alpha'))
 )
  GROUP BY d.`GenEx`;
```

And let me know what you get now.

Comment: The result is `GenEx->Cipro, Price->4.99 , CodeName->Alpha,Denvi,RST,Terx,Alpha,Denvi,RST,Terx,Alpha,Denvi,RST,Terx,Alpha,Denvi,RST,Terx`

Comment: it repeats 4x for some reason

Comment: Now check it. I have replaced the `WHERE` with `AND` in the query.